# How do I include sub-dependencies of a library with gradle and Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I have an app and a library that I wrote.  My issue is that when including the library as a jar (I see all of the classes included when decompiled),the app itself cannot interact with sub-classes from decencies of the library.

What is a good way to ensure that by including the library the app also pulls in the required dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

> What is a good way to ensure that by including the library the app also pulls in the required dependencies?

The best way is to publish the library in a maven repo (private or public).
In this way with gradle you will be able to download the library and all dependencies (described in the pom file).

Adding the jar (or an aar) in a project you have to add also the nested dependencies in the project since the jar and the aar don't contain the nested dependencies.